# Gson - how to parse dynamic JSON string with nested JSON?

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have JSON string with dynamic elements, till now I parse it into Map:

```
Map map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, 
        new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {}.getType());
```

Now I need to solve thsi situation - one of these dynamic variables could be another JSON string.

Do you have some advice ho to solve it? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** JSON string example added (formatted):

```
{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": {
        "subkey1": [
            "subvalue1",
            "subvalue1"
        ],
        "subkey‌​2": [
            "subvalue2"
        ]
    },
    "key4": "val3"
}
```

Comment: And this gives an error? If so, which?

Comment: Eg: {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3": {"subkey1":"subvalue1","subkey2":"subvalue2"},"key4":"val3"} but I don't a structure of this JSON, so I don't know if is there some nested json and if so, I don't know its structure.

Comment: Yes, there is an exception: Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 57

Comment: According to [this other question I found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239969/using-gson-giving-error-expected-begin-array-but-was-string) that should occur if your json-data is invalid (with a `[` in that case), but off the bat I can't see anything wrong with the json you posted.

Comment: Its weird, I'll check the structure but the JSON string is generated via PHP function json_encode() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Thanks for now.

Comment: Have you checked that it returns a valid JSON-string? Is the output you posted a result from your php-function? Additionally, you could just write `TypeToken.class` instead of your long thing there.

Comment: Yes, this is my php source. I assume json_encode(); generates valid JSON string. 
<?php
$foo = array();
$foo["key1"] = 'val1';
$foo["key2"] = 'val2';
$foo["key3"] = array('subkey1'=>'subvalue1','subkey2'=>'subvalue2');
$foo["key4"] = 'val3';
echo json_encode($foo);
?>

Comment: According to http://jsonlint.com/ is my JSON string valid.

Comment: Ignore my previous statement. Deserializing objects with generics require the `TypeToken`-thing you're doing. But could you elaborate what do you mean by "one of these dynamic variables could be another JSON string"?

Comment: I mean that in my JSON string can be nested another JSON string, this is situation I demonstrated few comments above - there is sub array in array. This nested JSON string can (sometime) exists but doesn't have to be there all the time. Our application must be able to handle these situations. P.S. In PHP manual is: "To summarise, always test that your JSON decoder can handle the output you generate from json_encode()." - so I need to verify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call another JSON string is just a json object. Change the Map value type to **Object** from **String**: TypeToken>

```
String jsonString = "{\"key1\":\"val1\",\"key2\":\"val2\",\"key3\": {\"subkey1\":\"subvalue1\",\"subkey2\":\"subvalue2\"},\"key4\":\"val3\"}";

Map<String, Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
}.getType());
```

The above example works with GSON 2.2.2. And sysout(map) produces

```
{key1=val1, key2=val2, key3={subkey1=subvalue1, subkey2=subvalue2}, key4=val3}
```

As a small improvement I'd suggest that you explicitly specify map type parameters, and use Map instead of HashMap for the TypeToken.

Comment: Yes, now it works, thank you. I loop through parsed Objects in Map and I am processing them - is there some way how to solve out if Object is another Map and not string value?

Comment: @user1315357 There are obviously ways to solve it. The question is what you want to do with it. You can test if a _value_ is a _Map_ using the _instanceof_ parameter. For example you could create some recursive method that prints out a value if it is a string or iterates over the values if it is a Map and recursively calls itself for every one of them.
If you consider this question answered, could you accept it please?

Comment: It doesn't work with this JSON: {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":{"subkey1":["subvalue1","subvalue1"],"subkey2":["subvalue2"]},"key4":"val3"} created by this PHP code (notice that subkey1 and subkey2 is an array and not a single value as before): 
`$foo = array();
$foo["key1"] = 'val1';
$foo["key2"] = 'val2';
$foo["key3"] = array('subkey1'=>array('subvalue1','subvalue1'),'subkey2'=>array('subvalue2'));
$foo["key4"] = 'val3';
var_dump(json_encode($foo));` "doesn't work" mean that this nested JSON object is not parsed and is returned as a String.