# json Arrays, START_ARRAY or BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson, ckan

I am strugling with my first Ckan application and from the reading i did i choose to use Gson. From Ckan, for testing, i try to get the user list by `http://192.168.1.2:5000/api/action/user_list`
This gives me

```
{"help":"http://192.168.1.2:5000/api/3/action/help_show?name=user_list",
   "success":true,
   "result":[
      {  "openid":null,
         "about":null,
         "display_name":"default",
         "name":"default",
         "created":"2015-06-09T22:17:22.228196",
         "email_hash":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
         "sysadmin":true,
         "activity_streams_email_notifications":false,
         "state":"active",
         "number_of_edits":0,
         "fullname":null,
         "id":"d5e49a3d-599d-49f3-9e20-826a03540357",
         "number_created_packages":0
      },    (..more data here...deleted for convenience)
      { "openid":null,
         "about":null,
         "display_name":"visitor",
         "name":"visitor",
         "created":"2015-06-09T22:16:52.785325",
         "email_hash":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
         "sysadmin":false,
         "activity_streams_email_notifications":false,
         "state":"active",
         "number_of_edits":0,
         "fullname":null,
         "id":"9d279d8a-c068-46a5-9516-ed9c8de2f13b",
         "number_created_packages":0
      }
   ]
}
```

My problem is how to read this using Java.
What I did was

```
class JsonUserReply{
    public String help;
    public boolean success;
    public JsonUsers[] userArray;
    JsonUserReply(){}
}
class JsonUsers{
    public String openid;
    public String about;
    public String display_name;
    public String name;
    public String created;
    public String email_hash;
    public boolean sysadmin;
    public boolean act_email_notif;//"activity_streams_email_notifications"
    public String state;
    public int edits;
    public String fullname;
    public String id;
    public int numb_cre_packs;//"number_created_packages"
    JsonUsers(){}
}
```

I use the first class because the data provided is "some data, {array of Objects}".

Folowing some tutorials i used this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<JsonUserReply>>(){}.getType();
Collection<JsonUserReply> enums = gson.fromJson(host, collectionType);
```

This gives me an error on the `fromJson` command of:

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

<strike>and the same error i get using this
`JsonUserReply myTypes = gson.fromJson(host,JsonUserReply.class);`</strike>
**Edit**
`JsonUserReply myTypes = gson.fromJson(host,JsonUserReply.class);`
throws `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $`

while digging around i found and used this*

```
  url = new URL(host); //("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=java&type=post");
  InputStream is = url.openStream();
  JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(is);
while (parser.hasNext()) {                 
                  Event e = parser.next();              
                   if (e == Event.KEY_NAME) {       
                       switch (parser.getString()) {
                       case "name":
                           parser.next();
                           System.out.println("Name "+parser.getString());                         
                           break;                   
                       case "result": 
                           System.out.println("RESULT1 "+parser.getString());
                           e=parser.next();                        
                           System.out.println("RESULT2 "+e.toString());             
                           break;
                       default: 
System.out.println(parser.getString());                        
                           break;
                       }
                   }
```

which even if it is way too complicated to use for my data as they are, it revieled something intresting. inside the `case "result":` i re-read the parser just to check whats its value. And it turns out that

> RESULT1 result
>   RESULT2 START_ARRAY
>   RESULT3 START_OBJECT

To me that means that the json object is sending the data with the keyword"START_ARRAY" but Gson is expecting BEGIN_ARRAY. Am i right? apparently these two are not the same. how can i use the Gson way to get the array from my data? Thanks

Comment: Please, have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10240062/2538372, are you sure it doesn't apply to your situation too?

Comment: @sainaen i cant see how that post can help me. I am a bit confused as I cant see where and how the json is executed.

Comment: Post the result of `JsonUserReply myTypes = gson.fromJson(host,JsonUserReply.class);`.

Comment: It throws the exception `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING`, will edit question, thought it was throwing begin_array