# Android Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm trying to read a Json using Retrofit library , however when I try to make the request get the following message : java.lang.IllegalStateException : Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 $ path

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide some code for us to work from.

Comment: Follows with Git project;
https://github.com/fredweb/MarvelMaterialDesign

Comment: https://github.com/fredweb/MarvelMaterialDesign/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/george/materialdesign/activity/CharacterList.java

Comment: Please copy the section of your code you need help with in here. Nobody's gonna go fishing for your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10240062/5528800

This is the most probable cause of your problem. You expect your backend to return a list of objects thus this code:

```
Call<List<Character>> call
```

, but what you should do is to create a model class because in your JSON list of characters maybe be named somehow for example "my_characters". If so, your model should be like this:

```
class Characters {
    List<Character> my_characters;
}
```

If that's the problem then you should use this model instead of `List<Character>`